# Let $(f_n) \subset L^1(\Omega)$ such that $f_n \le f_{n+1}$ and $\sup_n \int f_n \le r$. Does $f_n \to f$ a.e. imply $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. Let $(f_n) \subset L^1(\Omega)$ and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. Let's call

- *Assumption 1:* there is $r>0$ such that
  $$
  \int |f_n| \le r \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
  $$
- *Assumption 2:* $f_n \le f_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and there is $r>0$ such that
  $$
  \int f_n \le r \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
  $$

If *Assumption 1* holds, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671387/brezis-exercise-4-13) $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ by Fatou's lemma.

> Does $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ hold when we replace *Assumption 1* with *Assumption 2*?

Comment: (1) follows from Fatou's Lemma: $\int |f|\,d\mu\leq \liminf_n\int |f_n|\,d\mu\leq r$.(2) is a straight application of monotone convergence: $0\leq F_n=f_n-f_1\nearrow f-f_1$

Comment: @OliverDíaz doesn't monotone convergence require non-negativity of the sequence?

Comment: @fwd Replace $f_n$ with $f_n-f_1.$

Comment: @fwd: If all the elements of the sequence are integrable, a simple trick (see the edit to my comment) does the trick.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Akira: just did as a community wiki. This question did not require too much in my opinion, but now you have an answer for your purposes. Regards!

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have to accept an answer that solved my question :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) follows from Fatou's Lemma: $\int |f|\,d\mu\leq \liminf_n\int |f_n|\,d\mu\leq r$.

(2) is a straight application of monotone convergence: $0\leq F_n=f_n-f_1\nearrow f-f_1$